# File.delete() function works only first time then throws f noilet found for other images

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am storing uri for all files in a list which are in
Directory

```
"/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.pratiksahu.dokify/"
```

This is the function which is used to delete files

```
fun setupDeleteImageButtonListener() {
        deleteFileButton.setOnClickListener {
            if(selectedItemsImage.size>0)
            selectedItemsImage.forEach {
                File("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.pratiksahu.dokify/", it.path).delete()
                    .let { result ->
                        Log.d(TAG_DELETE, it.path + " <-- $result")
                    }
            }
            selectedItemsImage.clear() //using this to store image uri
            selectedItems.clear() //using this to store index which is being used in recyclerview with checkbox
            importedImagesAdapter?.setSelectedItems(selectedItems) //updating checkbox selected items
            imageList.clear() //Clearing list which is retrieved from scanning the directory when app starts
            imagePagerViewModel.initImages() // Refreshing available files list (Contains uri)
            importedImagesAdapter?.items = imageList //Setting new list to adapter
        }
    }
```

I am able to delete files in first batch , but if I try to delete files in second batch , File.delete() is not able to find the file though it is present in directory

[image]

Comment: are you getting an error message?

Comment: in the Log it is returning false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error , I was scanning the directory and storing the uri which had the full path in it

```
fun initImages() {
        _loading.value = true
        val path  = "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.pratiksahu.dokify/files/Pictures"
        val directory = File(path)
        if (directory.exists())
        {
            val files: Array<File> = directory.listFiles()
            if (files.size > 0) {
                Arrays.sort(files, Comparator.comparingLong(File::lastModified).reversed())
                val tempDocInfoList = ArrayList<DocInfo>()
                for (i in files.indices) {
                    val tempDocInfo = DocInfo(files[i].toUri() , files[i].name , files[i].length().toString())
                    tempDocInfoList.add(tempDocInfo)
                }
                setImage(tempDocInfoList)
            }
        }
        _loading.value = false
    }
```

Unlike in other scenarios where If I try to import from gallery or camera it won't have full path in it.
So all I had to change in my code was

```
File("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.pratiksahu.dokify/", it.path)

into 

File(it.path)
```